# Android: Spacer between 2 Listviews

Tags: android, listview, padding

How do I add a 20px space between two listviews:

```
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listStations" />
 SPACER???
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listSocial" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would suffice to set `paddingTop` or `paddingBottom` to `20px` on one of the `ListView`s. Alternatively, you can create an empty view (for instance a `TextView` with no text, or as mentioned by *@AljoshaBre* just a `View`), and set its `layout_height` to `20px`.

Answer (score 1):

For the first listview you can add

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
```